# How do I connect an existing solution in Visual Studio 2015 to an existing Project in Visual Studio Team Services Project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I have an existing solution on my desktop.  My IT administrator created a project on Visual Studio Team Services for me to connect my solution to.  However, I have no found any way that will actually work.  So far I have tried to:

First attempt. Result is all of my files have have the locked icon next to them as if they have been check in but there is no way to upload the code.
 1. Connect my Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2015 to my online account.
 2. Right click on my solution and click Add Solution to source control.

Second attempt. Result, same as first attempt.
 1. Go to visualstudio.com and select my project, then select the code tab. Click on clone in Visual Studio.
 2. In Visual Studio, open my solution and click Add Solution to source control.

I cannot find a location to enter my clone URL into my solution in Visual Studio. I checked in both Solution Explorer and Team Explorer and there appears to be no option.  This is very frustrating because Microsoft gives very little instruction online.

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC?

Comment: I am using Git.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using TFVC, you need to configure the workspace first after connecting to your team project from Team Explorer and move your solution/project to the workspace folder. And then you can right click on the solution to add it to source control and check in. Refer to this link for details: [Add an existing app](https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/code/share-your-code-in-tfvc-vs#app_add).

If you are using Git, you can clone the VSTS remote repository to your local machine from Team Explorer and copy your solution into the local Git repository folder, and then commit the changes and push to VSTS. Refer to this link for details: [Develop and share your code in Git using Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/code/share-your-code-in-git-vs). You can also convert the folder of your solution to a local Git repository and then push it to VSTS remote repository via following commands:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'commitcomment'
git remote add origin <vsts remote repository url>
git push origin master
```

Comment: sorry to ask a question in old post. what is the difference between VSTS GIT and Github GIT ? both are same ?. i saw project created in github GIT is accessible by anyone if we do not use paid version there. so VSTS GIT project is also accessible by any one or it is private always because VSTS is also free for 5 user.

Comment: @Thomas VSTS Git is private repository.

Comment: good answer. so what is difference between VSTS GIT and Github GIT ?

Comment: when people go for VSTS git and when Github git...can you mention any scenario please. thanks

Comment: @Thomas There isn't any difference, just Git repositories hosted on different service.

Comment: i heard there is a difference between git and tfvc. tfvc is centralize and git is local until we push the changes. am i right?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, you are right. Refer to this link for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Git repository for your solution in the VSTS project.
On the top left of the Code page is a dropdown with the option to create one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also launch VS 2015 from your team project overview page in your Visual Studio Team Services account:

[image: launch-vs-2015-team-project-overview-page]

You can get more details at [Connect to Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/setup-admin/team-services/connect-to-visual-studio-team-services).